# Copying content of strtok token in C

Tags: c, delimiter, strtok

Need to separate a string and then do another separation.

```
char *token = strtok(str, ",");
while(token){
    char *current_string = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(token));
    strcpy(current_string, token);

    char *tk = strtok(current_string, ":"); // KEY
    printf("key: %s ", tk);
    tk = strtok(0, ":");                    // VALUE
    printf("value: %s\r\n", tk);
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(0, ",");
}

printf("Done\n");
```

Trying to copy the content of `token`, but doing so messes with what remains in the `token` variable. It only processes one line instead of the three it should. I suspect the issue is with the `strcpy(current_string, token)` but unsure how I should go about it.

Comment: `strtok` is not re-entrant, which is why the line commented `// KEY` "messes with what remains". There is a re-entrant version available, perhaps `strtok_r` or `strtok_s`. These store the current state in a variable supplied by the caller, instead of an internal `static` variable.

Comment: You also have undefined behavior in the first two lines under `while`. You need one more element for the terminating null character. `char *current_string = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);`

Comment: Use `strdup` instead of `malloc` to copy a string.

Comment: @DanKorn Although `malloc()` is in the standard C library, sadly `strdup()` is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `strtok` function uses an internal static buffer to keep track of where it left off.  This means you can't use it to go back and forth parsing two different strings.

In your specific case, on this call:

```
token = strtok(0, ",");
```

The internal buffer is still pointing to a location inside of `current_string`, so attempting to go back to `token` won't work.

What you need to `strtok_r`.  This version takes an additional parameter to keep track of the current state.  That way, you can interchangeably parse two or more string by using a different state pointer for each one:

```
char *state1, *state2;
char *token = strtok_r(str, ",", &state1);
while(token){
    char *current_string = strdup(token);

    char *tk = strtok_r(current_string, ":", &state2); // KEY
    printf("key: %s ", tk);
    tk = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &state2);                    // VALUE
    printf("value: %s\r\n", tk);
    printf("%s\n", token);
    free(current_string);
    token = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &state1);
}

printf("Done\n");
```

Note that `NULL` was passed to the later `strtok_r` calls instead of `0`, since `NULL` may not necessarily be `0`.  Also, the calls to `malloc`/`strcpy` were replaced with a call to `strdup` which does the same, and also a call to `free` was added to prevent a memory leak.

The `strtok_r` is available on UNIX/Linux system.  On Windows, use `strtok_s` which works the same way.

Comment: Also note that the length passed to malloc is incorrect

Comment: @dbush ah, that makes sense. Didn't know about `strtok_r` or `strdup`. Makes things a bit easier. Thanks a lot for the help!